# android shared preferences doesn't work

Tags: android

I have an application and used 5-6 shared preferences in it. But today I tried something else and it didn't work and after that I noticed that shared preferences is the one that causes the error. My opener activity is  ActivtiyA then I click a button and ActivtiyB comes up.
ActivtiyA:

```
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ActivtiyA.this)
            .edit().putString("mana", "koko").apply();
```

ActivtiyB:

```
    Toast.makeText(this, "mana: "+ getIntent().getStringExtra("mana"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

What I see is mana: null.

Why?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you think that when you placed a value in your SharedPreferences that it would be magically available in the intent that launched you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you are trying to getExtra from an intent in activity B. In this case in ActivityA you should set an action filter and broadcast an Intent where you put that extra.In Activity B register a receiver with the same intent filter you put as action filter in ActivityA, and then you can grab the extra implementing the onReceive method.